# User-defined keyboard shortcut to delimit selected text with user-defined text delimiters

Tags: rstudio

Very often, I have to type the following:

```
{\texttt{something}}
```

Is there some possibility of creating a keyboard shortcut that, after having selected `something`, added `{\texttt{}}` to `something`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with an RStudio Add-in. These are relatively easy to build since they're just R packages containing regular R code, and you can add keyboard bindings for them to set up your own hotkeys. Instructions here for making addins:

https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/

Within your add-in you can use the `rstudioapi` package's document manipulation methods to locate the cursor/selected text and replace the range with the same value.

https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/reference/rstudio-documents.html

Comment: Thank you so much, @Jonathan, for your help!